# Как установить текущую схему (session set current_schema) глобально?

Tags: python, sql, oracle, cx-oracle

Изменяю текущую схему в функции:

```
db_dwh.cursor.execute("alter session set current_schema = SCHEMA_NAME")
```

Но когда с объектом `db_dwh` пытаюсь выполнить запрос к таблице, то получаю ошибку:

> ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

Для того, чтобы заработало надо снова выполнить команду, как показано выше.

Есть ли способ глобально установить текущую схему только один раз?

---

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [cx_oracle alter schema not working globally](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68176245) от участника [@Abhishek Kumar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16340011/abhishek-kumar)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/68176245

Answer (score 2):

По всей видимости, запрос выполняется с другим соединением. Похоже, используется пул соединений.

Вот некоторые доступные способы. Они могут быть полезны в зависимости от архитектуры приложения:

- [Connection.current_schema](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_manual/connection.html#Connection.current_schema) вместо явного ALTER SESSION. Это сэкономит временные затраты на выполнение `execute()`.
- [Connection Pool callbacks](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/connection_handling.html#session-callbacks-for-setting-pooled-connection-state) для эффективной установки состояния соединения. Если речь о установке текушей схемы глобально, то есть она всегда будет иметь одно и то же значение, то это решение в сочетании с атрибутом `Connection.current_schema` самое подходящее.

Пример для реализации:

```
def init_session(connection, requested_tag):
    connection.current_schema = 'ME'

pool = cx_Oracle.SessionPool (user='user', password='pass', dsn='dbsrv/pdb1', 
                              min=2, max=5, increment=1, encoding="UTF-8", 
                              sessionCallback=init_session)
        
connection = pool.acquire (tag='schema=me')

cursor = connection.cursor() 
cursor.execute("""select sys_context('USERENV', 'current_schema') from dual""")
print (cursor.fetchone()) # ('ME',)

pool.release(connection)
```

- [Heterogeneous connection pools](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/connection_handling.html#heterogeneous-and-homogeneous-connection-pools)

---

<sub>Свободный перевод [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68178099) от участника [@Christopher Jones](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4799035/christopher-jones)</sub>